# Can I specify the CAL for a SystemUser created with Dynamics CRM SDK

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I'm trying to insert a user programmatically with the Dynamics CRM SDK through `OrganizationServiceProxy.Create(SystemUser)`. The context is a Dynamics 2016 on premise server.

When I edit a user in the Dynamics web interface, I can choose a Licence Type for them. Currently, I have these options in the UI : Professional, Administrator, Basic, Device Professional, Device Basic, Essential, Device Essential, Enterprise and Device Enterprise. All my users need to have a *Basic* CAL.

Browsing through the properties assignable to a `SystemUser`, I cannot find one that would match these CAL values.

- The `UserLicenseType` property is an int. I couldn't find any documentation about it except [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.deployment.licensetype.aspx) which doesn't fit.
- `CALType` [doesn't match](http://nithinpaultech.blogspot.be/2013/02/crm-user-create-and-license-type-for.html) either - it has Full, Administrative, Limited, Device Full, Device Limited.

How can I specify a license for my `SystemUser`, if possible?

Comment: Is for on-premise or online?

Comment: on-premise. I'll add that to the question

Answer (score 0):

Here are the values that I've got from CRM 2016:

```
Caltype:
Professional = 0
Administrator = 1
Basic = 2
Device Professional = 3
Device Basic = 4
Essential = 5
Device Essential = 6
Enterprise = 7
Device Enterprise = 8

Accessmode:
Read-write = 0
Administrator = 1
Read = 2
```

You can get same values (and even more for accessmode) from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt608065.aspx)